# Why does span tag under div disappear when jQuery refreshes the data div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get("temp.php", function(temp) {
      $("deneme span").html(temp);
      $("#deneme").html(temp);

    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="de">
    <div class="den">
      <div class="dene">
        <div class="denem">
          <div class="deneme" id="deneme">
            <span></span><strong>&deg</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</center>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `.html()` **replaces** the HTML inside your div.

So with `$("deneme span").html(temp);` you are trying to fill-up the span, but then with `$("#deneme").html(temp);` you are removing the whole content and replacing it with `temp`.

I suggest you use `.append()` to ADD something to the div.

Comment: Thank you for the reply it seemed to do the trick! This was my first time asking a question on Stack overflow, and I am very new to html, php, and jquery. This is my first time I have ever used it.

Comment: @Kyle - don't forget to accept this as the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark: *(more code would help)*

```
$("deneme span").html(temp);
```

I noticed your including the `<span>` tag above.

Remove the `<span>` tag *ie*: `$("deneme")` if you don't want it to be effected by `.html(temp);`

After you've done that, try also adding: `display:inline-block;` to your `<span>` element for more stability to prevent it's position from moving with when the above element may.

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)